# Some UTF-8 Characters (Turkish) are Shown as HTML Numeric Code in jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I'm trying to create a PDF file that includes Turkish characters using **jsPDF** library. Before I change anything, it was creating PDF's like that:

[image]

"**Ğ**" character is looking empty and "**Ö**" character is shown as HTML numeric code which is `&#214;`

Code of this example:

```
var doc = new jsPDF(('p','pt','a4'));

doc.setFontType("bold");
doc.text(60, 28, 'Given name(s):');
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.text(88, 28, 'OĞUZHAN');
doc.setFontType("bold");
doc.text(60, 32, 'Place and date of birth:');
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.text(101, 32, 'KADIKÖY,');

doc.save('test.pdf');
```

Then I pick a font which has Turkish characters and .tff extension. I convert it with using [Font Converter](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html) that developer creates.

It gave me a .js file. After I include that file and .tff file to project, now I'm seeing final PDF like that:
[image]

"**Ğ**" character is looking good now but "**Ö**" character is still looking  `&#214;`

I just change the font using `doc.setFont("timestr");`:

```
var doc = new jsPDF(('p','pt','a4'));

doc.setFont("timestr");
doc.setFontType("bold");
doc.text(60, 28, 'Given name(s):');
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.text(88, 28, 'OĞUZHAN');
doc.setFontType("bold");
doc.text(60, 32, 'Place and date of birth:');
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.text(101, 32, 'KADIKÖY,');

doc.save('test.pdf');
```

Of course I include .js files that converter gave me:

```
<script src="/fonts/timestr-normal.js"></script>
<script src="/fonts/timestr-bold.js"></script>
<script src="/fonts/timestr-italic.js"></script>
<script src="/fonts/timestr-bolditalic.js"></script>
```

One of these .js files like that:

```
(function (jsPDFAPI) {
var font = 'AAEAAAAZAQA...'; // A very long string, I shorted it to show you
var callAddFont = function () {
this.addFileToVFS('timestr-normal.ttf', font);
this.addFont('timestr-normal.ttf', 'timestr', 'normal');
};
jsPDFAPI.events.push(['addFonts', callAddFont])
 })(jsPDF.API);
```

Where is the problem? It's very strange that "**Ğ**" character is looking normal after all these process but "**Ö**" character isn't looking properly, isn't it?

Comment: Tested here and is working fine for Ö https://jsfiddle.net/bortao/253Lcftv/

Comment: @ariel Yes I also tested on jsfiddle with the font I converted and everything was perfect, even **Ğ** and **Ö**. But it's not working on my project. It's looking like an encoding problem but I couldn't find it where is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay problem solved: Since I was using C#, I was getting these texts from my modal and I had to use them inside `Html.Raw()` method. So I wrote like that `Html.Raw(@model.Name)` and it solved the problem.